# chromedriver log append not overwrite

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, pytest

How can I get chromedriver to just append not overwrite with every new session?
I like to just enclose the `./chromedriver.log` for test-reports. but it holds only data from the last session.

A workaround is to add a last test to all session that print the `./chromedriver.log`
but it means one test for each session.

We use pytest so maybe it is possible to create a fixture to append to?

```py
elif os.environ['WEBDRIVER'].lower()=='chromeheadless':
  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
  options.add_argument('--headless')
  options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
  options.add_argument('--log-level=0')
  #options.add_argument('--incognito')
  #options.add_argument('--default-shm-size=32m')
  options.add_argument('--disable-translate')
  options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
  options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
  options.add_argument("--proxy-server='direct://'")
  options.add_argument("--proxy-bypass-list=*")
  #options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  #options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
  if os.environ.get('WEBDRIVER_LANG'):
    options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {'intl.accept_languages': os.environ.get('WEBDRIVER_LANG')})
  d = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME  # for console logging
  d['goog:loggingPrefs'] = { 'browser':'ALL', 'performance':'ALL'}
  s = Service()
  os.environ['CHROME_LOG_FILE'] = "./chromedriver.log"
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options, desired_capabilities=d, service_args=['--verbose', '--log-path=./chromedriver.log'])
```